# Overriding Protected Methods

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I have a very basic question.

I have 2 Parent Class under the same package. `Animal` Abstract Class and the `Machine` Class.

Now, the `Animal` Abstract Class has a protected method. I'm aware that protected methods are accessible if the classes are under the same package.

I can access that protected method in my `Machine` Class, and the question is.. Is it possible to override that protected method? Without extending the `Animal` Class.

Comment: Did you try to do it? What was the result?

Comment: Overriding comes after inheritance...what you are saying is not possible...:)

Comment: The answer is NO. You can override methods of 'Animal' only if you 'extend' your class with 'Animal'.     Like  "class Machine extends Animal{}"

Answer (score 37):

- protected - Can be overridden by subclasses, whether they are in the same package or not
- default (no access modifier) - can only be accessed or overridden if both the classes are in the same package

Comment: this one is the correct answer. Denis Salibio, You should play a bit with class hierarchy.

Answer (score 9):

You can only override methods through extension.

You can override a protected method with an anonymous subclass, if you like. E.g.

```
public class Animal {

    protected String getSound() {
        return "(Silence)";
    }

    public void speak() {
        System.out.println(getSound());
    }
}
```

In another class:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {

    Animal dog = new Animal() {

        @Override
        protected String getSound() {
            return "Woof!";
        }   
    }

    dog.speak();
}
```

Will output:

```
Woof!
```

Comment: Animal animal = new Dog();

I used this code to access the method, I'm just wondering if i can override the protected method then.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you could create an anonymous subclass of Animal to represent a dog, without actually creating a class named Dog.

Answer (score 2):

**No** , Overriding means inherit the behavior from parent class and that is not possible without extending the class.

```
public class PClass
{
    protected boolean methodA()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class CClass  extends PClass
{
    protected boolean methodA()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Run the code below to test it

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    PClass pc = new CClass();
    System.out.println(pc.methodA());

}
```

`O/p=false`

here we are overriding the behavior of `methodA`

Answer (score 0):

In order to override a method you have to extend that class. That's what overriding means:  having a method with the same signature as the super-class.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding by definition says..

*An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters) and return type as an instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method.*

So AFAIK if you don't extend the super class there is no way to override the method.